# Can see function from javascript file but not variables

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My directory structure is as follows:

```
src
 |--> js
  |--> more js files in nested folders
test
 |--> spec
       |--> js test files
```

If within one of my js tests in spec, if I try and call a function from a js file within my nested src directories, I can call the function fine. However, if I try and call a variable, it cannot find it, and I get a Reference Error.

My function (which is visible) is declared like so:

```
function myFunctionName() {
   ... some code ...
}
```

My variable is declared after the function, and not inside any other function, like so:

```
var myVar = '...';
```

I've also tried declaring myVar as a `const`, for the same result.

**In myTestSpec.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    describe('...', function() {
        it('...', function () {

            // Works
            expect(myFunctionName()).toEqual('...');

            // Doesn't work
            var newVar = myVar;            
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: How are your files being loaded from the spec runner? Are you using ES Modules with Webpack, or a similar setup?

Comment: I set up Karma using Yeoman, and included a few runners for jasmine and various browsers

Comment: I'm wondering because if you use a module loader like Webpack or Browserify to load your files as modules, these loaders typically wrap the code inside files in a closure/IIFE, so what looks like it should be a global variable will not be accessible

Comment: Agreed on that point. Instead of writing `function myFunctionName...`, try `window.myFunctionName = function...`

Comment: The problem is that the variables are not accessible, the functions can already be accessed

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this by just sticking any 'global' state I required into a function, to be returned as json. I now just need to call this function everytime I start a test.

This has a slight performance hit I guess as we need to recreate the state across multiple tests, however it's not production code (test only) so shouldn't be an issue, and it means I don't have to depend on another JS library such as require js..